# How Does Margin of Error Apply in Survey Where Respondents Select a Few of Several Choices

Tags: confidence-interval, survey

I have a 29% response rate from a survey asking respondents to identify which of 11 age groups their family members represented.  In general family size can range fro 1 to 6 members. In summing up all responses I have a sample size representing the distribution across 11 age groups of the entire population.  Based on Survey formula I learn that I have a 3% margin of error based on actual response rate for my total participant pool.  My question is does this 3% margin of error apply to each of the 11 age group categories?

Comment: I am getting a bit anxious about some feedback on this question.  After further thought I believe the Margin of Error applies at the whole community level.  So if I have a total pop of 10,000 then my MofE is +/- 300 people.  The next thought is I should not distribute this evenly across the 11 sub-groups that make up my community, life is never that ordered.  OTH it is not likely that all of the 300 would occur in a single sub-group.  So what is best way to handle?